# why 0x80000000 and its long form are different?

Tags: java, bit

I am trying to implement error code with bits. Its like:

```
public static final long ERROR_1 = 0x1;
public static final long ERROR_2 = 0x2;
public static final long ERROR_3 = 0x4;
public static final long ERROR_4 = 0x8;
.
.
.
```

but when i add `0x80000000`, output is `-2147483648`.  If change the value to `0x80000000l`, output is `2147483648`. I am confused. Can somebody expain me why output is different and which one i should use?

```
System.out.println(0x80000000);       //-2147483648
System.out.println(0x80000000l);      //2147483648
```

Comment: This happens with signed integer overflow,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is integer overflow. The maximum number that a signed integer can represent is `0x7FFFFFFF`, since in two's complement `0x80000000 = -2147483648`.

If the most significant bit is set in a two's complement integer that means the number is negative, with `0x80000000 = -2147483648` and `0xFFFFFFFF = -1`.

Long can display much higher numbers. There you'd only get an overflow at `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = -9223372036854775808`

Answer (score 3):

Because `0x80000000` is a hexadecimal `int`, which overflows `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, whereas `0x80000000l` is a `long` and won't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In java, `int` and `Integer` are signed, and use 31 bits to store positive values.

`2147483648` is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE, as it needs more than 31 bits to store it.

`Long` and `long` use 63-bits to store positive values.  Thus `2147483648` can be represented in a `long`.

Comment: Not quite correct. Java uses two's complement, so the most significant bit is not only the sign, but also reverses the count direction and subtracts 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're first displaying an int, then a long.

32-bit vs 64-bit, 2's complement.